# How do you configure /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac on CentOS 6 using authconfig?

Tags: authentication, centos6, pam

I'm trying to replace the cracklib module with passwdqc. Every time I do an authconfig --update (or --updateall), the changes I make on the system-auth-ac file goes away. The authconfig command line or system-config-authentication don't have any options pertaining to passwdqc. I also need to add arguments to the passwdqc module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable `pam_passwdqc`:

- Replace the `pam_cracklib` line in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` with `pam_passwdqc`.
- Remove `USECRACKLIB=yes` from `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig`

Now, run `authconfig --update` and you should find that `pam_passwdqc` is still enabled.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. To change it back to use cracklib, all I had to do was to change USECRACKLIB to yes in /etc/sysconfig/authconfig, or change the passwdqc line in /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac back to cracklib. I did not have to change 2 configuration files. Is there any documentation about this? I couldn't find in the man pages of authconfig, system-auth-ac and passwdqc anything relating /etc/sysconfig/authconfig to any of the /etc/pam.d/ files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do changes as below so that it will not be editing by authconfig command,

create a symlink to any file other than `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` as authconfig command make changes on `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`

~~~

```
unlink /etc/pam.d/system-auth
cp /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac /etc/pam.d/system-auth-permanent
ln -s /etc/pam.d/system-auth-permanent /etc/pam.d/system-auth
```

~~~

Now run `authconfig --update`